# OrchardCMS: How to access Content Menu Item boolean field in cshtml view

Tags: orchardcms

In orchard, I've added a boolean field called "IsDone" to the built in Content Menu Item content part via that Admin interface.  I've then picked an item in Navigation and set the option to "yes" for the corresponding field i added.

In my custom theme, I've copied over MenuItem.cshtml.

How would I get the value of my custom "IsDone" field here?

I've tried something like

```
 dynamic item = Model.ContentItem;
 var myValue = item.MenuItem.IsDone.Value;
```

but I'm pretty sure my syntax is incorrect (because i get null binding errors at runtime).

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

First i suggest you use the shape alternate `MenuItemLink-ContentMenuItem.cshtml` instead of `MenuItem.cshtml` to target the content menu item directly.

Secondly, the field is attached to the `ContentPart` of the menu item. The following code retrieves the boolean field from this content part:

```cs
@using Orchard.ContentManagement;
@using System.Linq;

@{
  Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentItem lContentItem = Model.Content.ContentItem;

  var lBooleanField = lContentItem
    .Parts
    .Where(p => p.PartDefinition.Name == "ContentMenuItem") // *1
    .SelectMany(p => p.Fields.Where(f => f.Name == "IsDone"))
    .FirstOrDefault() as Orchard.Fields.Fields.BooleanField;

  if (lBooleanField != null)
  {
    bool? v = lBooleanField.Value;

    if (v.HasValue)
    {
      if (v.Value)
      {
        @("done")
      }
      else
      {
        @("not done")
      }
    }
    else
    {
      @("not done")
    }
  }
}
```

***1**
Sadly you cannot simply write `lContentItem.As<Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentPart>()` here as the first part in the part list is derived from this type, thus you would receive the wrong part.

Answer (score 4):

While @ViRuSTriNiTy's answer is probably correct, it doesn't take advantage of the power of the dynamic objects that Orchard provides.

This is working for me but is a much shorter version:

```
<a href="@Model.Href">@Model.Text</a>

@{
    bool? IsDone = Model.Content.ContentMenuItem.IsDone.Value;
    var IsItDoneThough = (IsDone.HasValue ? IsDone.Value : false);
}

<p>Is it done? @IsItDoneThough</p>
```

You can see that in the first line I pull in the `IsDone` field using the dynamic nature of the `Model`.

For some reason (I'm sure there is a good one somewhere) the `BooleanField` uses a `bool?` as its backing value. This means that if you create the new menu item and just leave the checkbox blank it will be `null` when you query it. After you have saved it as checked it will be `true` and then if you go back and uncheck it then it will have the value `false`.

The second line that I've provided `IsItDoneThough` checks if it has a value yet. If it does then it uses that, otherwise it assumes it to be `false`.

### Shape Alternate

@ViRuSTriNiTy's other advice, to change it to use the `MenuItemLink-ContentMenuItem.cshtml` instead of `MenuItem.cshtml` is also important.

The field doesn't exist on other menu items so it will crash if you try to access it. Just rename the `.cshtml` file to fix this.

### Dynamic Model

Just to wrap this up with a little bit of insight as to how I got there (I'm still learning this as well) the way I figured it out is as follows:

`.Content` is a way of casting the current content item to dynamic, so you can use the dynamic advantages with the rest of line;

When you add the field in the admin panel it looks like it should be right there on the ContentItem, however it actually creates an invisible ContentPart to contain them and calls it whatever the ContentItem's type is.

So if you had added this field to a `Page` content type you would have used `Model.Content.Page.IsDone.Value`. If you had made a new content type called banana it would be `Model.Content.Banana.IsDone.Value`, etc.

Once you are inside the "invisible" part which holds the fields you can finally get at `IsDone`. This won't give you the actual value yet though. Each `Field` has its own properties which you can look up in the source code. the `IsDone` is actually a `BooleanField` and it exposes its data via the `Value` property.

Try doing a solution-wide search for `: ContentField` to see the classes for each of the fields you have available.

Hopefully this will have explained things clearly but I have actually written about using fields [in a blog post](http://articles.runtings.co.uk/2015/10/orchard-cms-quick-tipif-you-cast-it.html) and as part of my [getting started with modules course](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Getting-Started-with-Modules/) over on the official docs (its way down in part 3 if you're curious).

### Using built-in features instead of IsDone

This seems like a strange approach to do it this way. If you have a Content Item like a Page then you can just use the "Show on a menu" setting on the page.

Go to admin > content > open the page > down near the bottom you will find "Show on a menu":

[image: Show on a menu option]

This will automatically put it into your navigation and then you can move it around to where you want:

[image: Navigation]

After it "IsDone" you can just go back and untick the "Show on a menu" option.

### Setting up the alternative .cshtml

To clarify your comments about how to use the alternative, you need to

1. Copy the file you have at `Orchard.Core/Shapes/Views/MenuItem.cshtml` over to your theme's view folder so its `/Views/MenuItem.cshtml`
2. Rename the copy in your theme to `MenuItem-ContentMenuItem.cshtml`
3. Delete probably everything in it and paste in my sample at the start of this post. You don't want most of the original `MenuItem.cshtml` code in there as it is doing some special tricks to change itself into a different shape which isn't what you want.
4. Reset your original `Orchard.Core/Shapes/Views/MenuItem.cshtml` back to the factory default, grab it from the [official Orchard repository](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/dev/src/Orchard.Web/Core/Shapes/Views/MenuItem.cshtml)

### Understanding the view names

From your comments you asked about creating more specific views (known as alternates). You can use something call the Shape Tracer to view these. The name of them follows a certain pattern which makes them more and more specific.

You can learn about the alternates on the official docs site:

- [Accessing and Rendering Shapes](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Accessing-and-rendering-shapes/)
- [Alternates](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Alternates/)

To figure out what shape is being used and what alternates are available you can use the shape tracing module which is documented here:

- [Getting Started with Shape Tracing](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Customizing-Orchard-using-Designer-Helper-Tools/)

Comment: thanks. Sorry I'm VERY new to orchard.  I've been using Orchard.Core/Shapes/Views/MenuItem.cshtml  If I use Orchard.Core/Navigation/Views/MenuItemLink-Shape_MenuTiem.cshtml can I copy it to the same place in my theme project?     Also can you clarify on renaming the .cshtml file?  How would I use the view if I rename it?    I'm using the IsDone field to determine whether or not i even render the menu item.  thank you in advance

Comment: ah ok it sounds like you haven't yet got your head around alternates and theming orchard :) You shouldn't be editing the files directly in Orchard.Core. Part of the power of Orchard is that you can expand everything. You can override a view inside your theme which is what we are talking about. Orchard has quite the steep learning curve :) I'll add some more to my answer.

Comment: @rtpHarry Good answer, some new stuff for me explained here and there, but however, what happens when the field is not configured and the line `Model.Content.ContentMenuItem.IsDone.Value` is executed? My bet is, it crashes. That's why i don't recommend using this style of writing things although it looks nicer.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy yes it would crash if the field was deleted. The field should exist on every `ContentMenuItem` though which is why i seconded your advice to use the alt view. I guess it depends if you trust your administrators :) You could write it defensively using the dynamic notation as well though, with a lot of null checks instead of the one-liner I suggested.

Comment: Thanks @rtpHarry  and ViRuSTriNiTy  - to clarify,  I've been copying Orchard.Core/Shapes/Views/MenuItem.chsml    to my themes view folder.  what I can't wrap my mind around is renaming it to that particular name  MenuItem-ContentMenuItem.cshtml  .    Does orchard merely append (or replace?) the core instance with this because the view begins with "MenuItem" ?   Sorry, these questions in the comments are going a little beyond the scope of my initial question, but your responses have been VERY helpful.

Comment: @rtpHarry  also.. sorry I left it out because i didn/t want to complicate the question..  but I have some other logic that had determined whether or not a user is from a certain IP range, and based on that AND whether that option is checked, I would choose whether or not to display the menu item.  In a nutshell, I need users visiting from outside my organization to get a slightly different menu

Comment: I've added some more to my answer on the end.

Comment: @NoCarrier Please post new questions when new requirements arise. We cannot discuss this in the comments.